# Why does this JSON.parse code not work?

Tags: php, javascript, json, parsing, encode

I am trying to pass json encoded values from a php script to a, GnuBookTest.js, javascript file that initiates a Bookreader object and use the values i have passed in via the variable i named "result".

The php script is sending the values like:

```
<div id="bookreader">
 <div id="BookReader" style="left:10px; right:10px; top:30px; bottom:30px;">x</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">var result = {"istack":"zi94sm65\/BUCY\/BUCY200707170530PM","leafCount":"14","wArr":"[893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893,893]","hArr":"[1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155,1155]","leafArr":"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]","sd":"[\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\",\"RIGHT\",\"LEFT\"]"}</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/application/js/GnuBookTest.js"></script>
 </div>
</div>
```

and in the GnuBookTest.js file i am trying to use the values like:

```
br = new BookReader();

// Return the width of a given page.
br.getPageWidth = function(index) {
     return this.pageW[index];
}

// Return the height of a given page.
br.getPageHeight = function(index) {
    return this.pageH[index];
}

br.pageW = JSON.parse(result.wArr);

br.pageH = JSON.parse(result.hArr);

br.leafMap = JSON.parse(result.leafArr);

//istack is an url fragment for location of image files
var istack = result.istack;
.
.
.
```

Using JSON.parse as i have written it above loads the Bookreader and uses my values correctly in a few web-browsers: Firefox, IE8, and desktop-Safari; but does not work at all in mac-Chrome, mobile-Safari, plus older versions of IE. Mobile safari keeps giving me a reference error msg: can't find variable: JSON. The other browsers just do not load the Bookreader and show the "x" instead, like they did not get the values from the php script.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Older browsers don't have native JSON support. You'll likely have to [include it](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) manually.

Answer (score 1):

Older browsers do support JSON, they just don't support `JSON.parse`. To load JSON data in older browsers you can simply use

```
var obj = eval('('+jsonStr + ')');
```

Comment: $Jeff Beaman, I am facing with the same issue. It works on other browsers but not IE. I havet this piece of code: $.ajax({
 
        url: 'get_cpu.php', 
        success: function(data) {
  var myObj = JSON.parse(data);  Any ideas how I could modify this? I tryied your mehtod, no luck.